# Website fails with multiple users

Tags: web, server, clients

I apologize if this is asked, but I wasn't sure how this question would be worded. I'm making a website for my class of 16 students which I currently have hosted on freehostia.com   When I test the website with 1-2 computers it works fine. But when I have 16 people using it at same time images fail to load and sometimes the connection fails completely. Is there something I'm missing or is this a server problem?

The only message I have over and over again in the error log is:

> [Tue Sep 01 01:17:52 2015] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] File does not exist: /services/users/zfh1p1/miclug/www/mathexp.org/favicon.ico

I already googled that and added a favicon.ico file, but doubt this was the issue I'm having.  Thanks ahead of time!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the resources the page loaded is linked and how your connection to the internet is configured, you would hit the  maximum number of connection per hosts ( and unlikely the maximum number of connection to the server ) or even the bandwidth limit in a few second of time.

Try to make your page link to less resources, consider using a CDN, or multiple host, and if you can consider using a proxy server for the classroom.

Way to reduce the number of connection to the server :

- Inline you javascript (include your JS into your HTML )
- If inlining is difficult, of scruipt are shred between page consider concatenating the shared scripts into one file
- minify you javascript
- inline your CSS ( same as above with the CSS )
- same strategies as the ones used for javascript
- reduce the number of image linked in one page
- resize you image to be of the size displayed in the page

Comment: Thanks for information. I have a feeling your right because sometimes images won't load, or the entire page wills top loading for a few minutes. The part I have a hard part of understanding is that I'm hitting a limit so easily. At any one time there is no more than 7 images being shown and 16 students using the site. The site is cycling through images of questions as students answer them. Since all connections are coming from the same location how would a proxy server or CDN help? Also inlining css and javascripts sounds like it would make construction of "bigger" websites impracticable?

Comment: How large are the images ? And 16*(7 images) already makes 112 connection that might use the same IP address, which could be suspect

Comment: 5 images under 600 bytes and 1 image 134 kb.